# Listening to custom events but set the code outside the component's HTML

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I'm reading the docs online and the only way I can declare a "custom event" is like this:

```
<my-component v-on:my-event="doSomething"></my-component>
```

This just calls the event, `doSomething`, **that's on my methods object**, when I call it from a child component like this:

```
 this.$emit("doSomething", "a string value") ;
```

Now, I don't believe there is no other way of declaring an event outside the `<my-component>` tag, say on the `export default` object? Because if I'm listening to a lot of events the `<my-component>` tag it will be extremely uncomfortable to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You should emit the name of the event. In this case `this.$emit("my-event", "a string value") ;`

Comment: thats for invoking it, but I want to declare the v-on in the  export default { } initialization of the component, it is possible?

Comment: I don't think that is possible. But if you're working with lots of events I would recommed trying a pub/sub library like https://github.com/developit/mitt

Answer (score 0):

For the souls looking to add programmatically events to the parent component you can add it like this:

```
export default {
   name: testComponent,
   created(){
      this.$on("mycustomevent", this.customevent);
   },
  methods:{
    customevent(){
      alert("this is a custom event");
    }
  }  
}
```

then on the child component you can call the event like this (using for example:mounted() )

```
mounted(){
   this.$emit('mycustomevent');
}
```

this is usefull for Dynamic layout wrapper components since you cannot declare custom events for custom themes on App.vue in my case:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">    
      <component :is="layout">
          <router-view :layout.sync="layout"/>
      </component>
  </div>
</template>
```

which depend on a variable and must work for all templates or views (in my case layout)
now you can have your custom events started within the js code without the need to declare them in the js!